# Create folder in user's programs menu folder on user deman during application intallation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, setup-project

I am creating windows application setup project in visual studio. I want to give option to user to create application folder in user's program menu during application installation.

How can achieve this? Can I set the 'AlwaysCreate' property of user's program menu during setup installations? If yes where should i code to get user input to set this property?

[image]

I am newbie to create windows application setup, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this. The underlying problem is that despite the setup project UI you can't put conditions on folders, only files. Sure, you could set alwayscreate, but that is a build time action, not an install time action.

The general approach might be to use one of those standard UI dialogs that can be added to the setup UI, like the RadioButtons dialog. When that button is on then a property will be set, and you can use that property in a condition in a custom action you'd write to create the folders. That might work, but you'd need to deal with removing them at uninstall, and being aware of a repair running your custom action again. I haven't ever seen a setup that asked that kind of question. How would I as the person running the install possibly know how to answer that question, and why would I  need empty folders in the Program menu that don't refer to anything? It's one of those questions that developers think are flexible but that users think are pointless :)